# Github does not reflect the newly created repo as a github profile

Tags: github, markdown

I created a brand new account on [Github](https://github.com/alok-38) and for some reason my profile is not getting reflected.

After initializing the repository, I tried pulling and pushing multiple times.

All I see is the newly created repository but not my profile.

Comment: I think this is a question for [GitHub Support](https://git.io/c), but did you perhaps mean to [add a profile README](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/customizing-your-profile/managing-your-profile-readme)?

Comment: Yes. I meant to add a profile README.

Comment: I want to make it appear like on of the profile in here https://eddiehubcommunity.github.io/awesome-github-profiles/profiles

Comment: I think you should just be able to rename the repo to alok-38 (your username), then.

Comment: Can I post it as an answer? (You can also do it yourself and accept it in two days if that’s your preference. I don’t mind either way.)

Comment: Sure. I'm on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to name the repository as same as your GitHub user name. GitHub will automatically add it as a profile READ-ME once you you push it from your local repository.

Comment: don't you also need to put the readme in a `/profile` folder?

Comment: This is my folder structure
```.

├── favicon.png
├── github-profile.png
├── README.md
└── scrimba.png

0 directories, 4 files

```